# Adjusting width for mobile devices

Tags: android, html, viewport, mobile-devices

I rewrote my web site to be formatted for mobile devices.  However, the display width is inconsistent on different devices.  On my android device the width looks fine but on another person's android device the width is much smaller and therefore unreadable.

I use the following viewport in my html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /
```

This is my main div in the html page:

```
     <div id="maindiv" style="margin-left:1.0em; margin-right:0.5em">
```

Do I need to put a width paramter in my main div?  Or can anyone tell me what I should do to ensure a uniform body width for mobile devices?

Comment: Is this android related? Or mobile in general?

Comment: It is mobile in general.  I happened to notice that two different Android phones had different widths when displaying the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to build a responsive site. If you have fixed widths on divs you'll need to use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Since IE 8 and older don't support media queries you can use a plugin like [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). With this plugin you'll only need to add it to your page and use media queries like you normally would.

Do you have a link to the site?

Media queries can be used for targeting specific browser/device width so you can style things only when the browser/device meets that media querier specification.

However, if you change #maindiv width to 100% or use max-width, I believe this will fix your problem. Also in an external style sheet or on the page you'll want to add the following css to make your images responsive:

```
img {
max-width:100%
height:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Also remove:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

and put:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Can I use @media max-width as a variable to use in a calculation for my body width or must I use it as described in the examples in css media queries?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention the link to the website.  The link is http://www.minonktalk.com/mobile/indexm.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I will try that and see if I can fix the problem.  Thanks for introducing me to css media queries also.

Comment: I made your suggested changes and asked the person who gets the screwed up version on his Android phone and he said it still has a narrow width.  He has a goofy phone I never heard of.  Is it possible it is the phone and not the web page?

Comment: I clicked the link you provided and didn't see any changes.

Comment: The name of the phone is Kyocera.  I never hear of it.

Comment: Does the format look ok on your phone or is it compressed also?